When training a pytorch model, the loss of the first batch can be backpropagated, but an error is reported in the second batch?
Source code of error reporting part:
for i in range(2):
    text = ['What is past is prologue'] * 2
    token = [tokenizer.encode(s, bos=True, eos=False) for s in text]
    token = torch.LongTensor(token).to('cuda')  # shape: 2*7
    output = model(token)  # shape: 2*7*128256
    label = token  # assume label equals input
    loss = nn.functional.cross_entropy(output.transpose(1, 2), label)
    loss.backward()
    opt.step()
    print(loss)

And the output of terminal:
tensor(11.8506, device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<NllLoss2DBackward0>)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/lc/llama3/train.py", line 126, in <module>
    loss.backward()
  File "/home/lc/anaconda3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/_tensor.py", line 521, in backward
    torch.autograd.backward(
  File "/home/lc/anaconda3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/__init__.py", line 289, in backward
    _engine_run_backward(
  File "/home/lc/anaconda3/envs/llama/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/graph.py", line 768, in _engine_run_backward
    return Variable._execution_engine.run_backward(  # Calls into the C++ engine to run the backward pass
RuntimeError: Trying to backward through the graph a second time (or directly access saved tensors after they have already been freed). Saved intermediate values of the graph are freed when you call .backward() or autograd.grad(). Specify retain_graph=True if you need to backward through the graph a second time or if you need to access saved tensors after calling backward.

I encountered the error when trying to train a tiny Llama. Finally, I simplified the error code into the code I posted, but I still couldn't locate the error.

Your code looks fine and I can't reproduce the same error. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example? This means you should include a model and a tokenizer. If it too long please try to use a simple model and tokenizer just to reproduce this error.
